# PHP:include file

Tags: php

I have a DB file content my DB info. the file db.php located on my mother's folder [here apps folder]. Now, how can I include the db.php file anywhere on the project using `base_url()`? Here is my base url function:

```
function base_url() {
    return "http://localhost/apps";
}
```

I tried like this way but it does not work.

```
$link=base_url()."/"."db.php";      
include('$link');
```

Can anybody please help>

Thanks
riad

Comment: What do you mean by "not works"? Do you get a compile error, or the output behavior is different?

Comment: Why it doesn't work? Wich error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include('../db.php');
```

"../" will reapeat (eg '../../../db.php') as depth of the file from which you are including

you can use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] var as the base URL/PATH too

Comment: I think having to deal with `../..` is what he wants to avoid with his function.

Comment: thanks sadat.i use 
         $link =$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/apps/db.php";  
  include  $link;
it works..

Answer (score 3):

`base_url()` needs to return a file path here, not a `http://` URL.

(It would then probably make sense to rename it to `base_path()`)

Comment: but the base url i used whole the porject..so the filename cannot be return.that's why i added the file name after the base_url function.
the $link variable properly shown the result.But cannot include the fiel.OR any other way u know to include the file using url??

Comment: @riad including the file through an URL is stupid unless it is what you *specifically* want. Any PHP code in it will be parsed *before inclusion*, and a web server process started. You will usually want to use a file path.

Answer (score 2):

multiple problems.

1. `include('$link');` will never ever work because the single quotes mean the literal string $link and not the value of the variable, you'll be needing to use `include($link)` or `include("$link");`
2. include is a language construct not a function, so you only need `include $link;`
3. stipulating "/" as the directory separator could cause problems, PHP provides a constant for you to use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`
4. your base_url function should return a file path not an URL
5. base_url should probably just be a constant seeing as it won't change

here's a version which should work for you

```
function application_root()
{
  return dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}
$link = application_root() . 'db.php';
include $link;
```

Comment: I disagree with 2. and 3. and not sure about 5. but +1 for noticing 1. :)

Comment: @Pekka unsure how you can disagree with 2?? include simply *is* a construct - as for 3, if the script has to be any kind of portable, then best to use the native OS directory separator perhaps..

Comment: Re 2) I meant, it is fine to put the argument into brackets for consistency's sake. Your statement is correct though, they are not needed. Re 3) Nope, separators are automatically translated on Windows as well, it is usually okay to use forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Within [single quotes](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) variable occurrences like your `$link` are not substituted by their values. But you can simply write this:

```
$link = base_url()."/db.php";
include $link;
```

Now if this works as expected depends on whether you want the source code of *db.php* to be included or just the output of *db.php*. Because working on the filesystem gets you the source code while requesting it via HTTP gets you the output.

Comment: @riad yes, because you are using a URL (additionally, an incorrect one) as your inclusion path. I'll bet you a beer it's not what you want. But I've said it thrice now, I'm not going to repeat myself any more.